# DDD - price calculation when adding item to order / receipt

Tags: domain-driven-design, business-logic

I'm trying to apply DDD in my latest project. Though I'm having a problem identifying where to put some business logic/calculation.

First I'm going to describe the business flow and then how I'm thinking of implementing this.

Business flow:
It's simply about adding a receipt item(s) to a receipt. However, the price of the item depends on the type of customer and the number of items.

i.e: Customer of type 'A' would like to purchase 2 meals. In his set up, he is allowed to have 1 lunch discounted, but because he is very hungry, he takes 2. The first meal should be for 4 eur (discounted), the second should be 6 eur (full price).

What I'm thinking is:

**Product** - an entity (of different bounded context, will only be used as an input param) - fields: code, name, ...,  **collection of prices** each for a different customer type.

**ReceiptItem** - entity -fields: product code, product name, count, price, ...
**Receipt** as Aggregate root - fields:
     customer (entity) - contains collection of ReceiptItems

On the Receipt, there will a method `addItem(Product product, int count)` and I plan to add the correct price calculation inside this method.

Returning to our example: `receipt.addItem('menu1', 2)`

So I would check the customer type and how many lunches he is allowed to have discounted. Given the example above, I would see, that he is allowed one. I then need to get the actual discounted price and I would get that directly from the product that exposes a method getCustomersPrice(customerid).
In the end, I will end up with two receipt items being added to Receipt. They will both have the same product code, but different prices. (In case the allowance would be 2 or more, I would only add one item to the collection with the discounted price, but count would the 2).

Would you say, that this is a good approach? I'm worried about passing the product as an input parameter to addItem. As it seems to create a tight coupling.

Thank you.

Comment: Right now I’m looking at a receipt from a groceries store. The receipt contains some discounts along with products. The discounts are listed as separate items and products are listed with full price. This way no product should “know” its price for a particular customer. But customer may have a number of discounts that are applicable to different products and can be added to an order if eligible.

Comment: I like this, it actually allows to keep the domain object rather clean containing only essentials and at the same time a flexibility for different rule sets. Thanks a nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

The `Receipt` aggregate root should be smaller: `Receipt` has `ReceiptItem`s, which is fine, but `Customer` should be its own aggregate root. A customer exists independently of receipts, plus small aggregates are preferred.

`Product` is also a separate domain object within this bounded context, even though products also exist in a separate bounded context. `Product` also needs to be outside of the `Receipt` aggregate.

Given the fact that there are several aggregate roots, the logic to add a product to a receipt touches more than one aggregate. Thus, the logic cannot reside inside the `Receipt` aggregate nor any other aggregate. Such logic is best placed into a `Domain service` (which may reside in the same package as the `Receipt` aggregate), such as:

```
public class ReceiptService {

    void addItem(ReceiptId aReceiptid, ProductId aProductId, int quantity) {

        // business logic to determine price per item
        // ...

        // for each item, forward item creation to receipt:
        receipt.addItem(productIdOrName, priceOfItem);
    }
}
```

The Domain service combines data of various aggregates in order to determine the price per item. The internal logic to create a `ReceiptItem` and insert it into the collection of receipt items is best forwarded to the `Receipt` aggregate.

Comment: Thanks, I do see now that it's really a cross baundry operation. However, I'm struggling with one thing. Once saved, the receipt can not be altered. So if I'm invoking the add item method, that means, the receipt has not been persisted yet and I therefore do not have a receiptId at that time. I assume, the idea was to pull all required entities from the db based on the ids, but that will not work for recept. So I'll probably have to use the receipt object directly as input param.

Comment: On the second thought, I realize now, that since this is a javaFx application, I was looking at it from a statefull perspective. So in a stateless, that would certainly work. I of course have to persist a receipt in an invalid state (Receipt without at least one receipt item, does not make sense). I'm honestly not used to using a default access level, but seems to me, that this is exactly what is needed in this case as all the major methods (add item, delete item, update count) will need to be handled by a service method due to business logic requiring different contexts. Sounds OK?

Comment: Persisting a receipt in an invalid state (without receipt item) certainly isn't ideal. Either work with item instead of the yet-non-existing id. Or, instead of `addItem` implement a `createReceipt(Collection productsAndQuantities)` method, which creates the receipt and the receiptItems.